# Histogram in class interval in R

Tags: r, histogram

I need to plot an histogram, but my data are in an class interval.

the following are my inferior limit and superior.

```
xinf=c(0,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5)
xsup=c(10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5,30)
```

frequency:

```
Fo=c(2,5,16,42,69,51,32,23,9,1)
```

I don't know how to plot an histogram with this data.

Answer (score 2):

Because your data is already summarized, I won't be making a "proper" histogram. Instead, we can fake it with a bar plot:

```
barplot(Fo, width = xsup-xinf)
```

[image]

One of the nuances is that since it is a bar plot, there are spaces between the bars. This can be removed with:

```
barplot(Fo, width = xsup-xinf, space = 0)
```

[image]

or some other near-zero value.

Other optional components: `axis(1)`, `barplot(..., main="My Bars")`.

[image]

As @EdwardCarney started to suggest, you can refine the axis like this:

```
barplot(Fo, width = xsup-xinf, space = 0, main = "My Bars")
lbls <- sort(union(xinf, xsup))
axis(1, labels = lbls, at = lbls, las = 2)
```

[image]

(His suggestion was leaning towards centers of the bins, here I opted for the boundaries of them. Either way, you have options. Note that if you do not set `space=0` then you have to adjust the locations of the labels, since everything will be spaced out.)

Comment: I like the barplot too for these data. I added the center of the class intervals using the `names.arg` parameter as follows: `barplot(Fo, las=1, names.arg=as.character((xsup-xinf)/2+xinf), ylim=c(0,75))`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
hist(rep((xinf+xsup)/2, Fo), breaks = union(xinf,xsup), 
     xlab = 'Variable name', main='Histogram')
```

Maybe I would change variables `xinf` and `xsup` by

```
xinf=c(9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5)
xsup=c(10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5,19.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
# data
Fo=c(2,5,16,42,69,51,32,23,9,1)
xinf=c(0,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5)

# breaks for histogram bars
breaks = c(xinf, 30)

# make a histogram with temp data
h = hist(rep(1, length(Fo)), breaks = xx, plot = FALSE)
# Fill the density and counts manually 
h$density = Fo / sum(Fo) 
h$counts = Fo
plot(h, freq = TRUE)
```

Do note that the `freq = TRUE` part is necessary to get counts on the y-axis. It also gives a warning message about the areas. Also, for the density estimation you could use something more sophisticated than what I used.